# Insert several rows from 1st table to the 2nd with ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert, insertion

I wonder how to implement this with ContentProvider?
I insert several rows from table to another with single select statment:

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2,...) 
     select field1, field2... from table2 where ...
```

If I should use insert method, I cannot get this several new id..

edit: If this is **insert** method what **Uri** I should return?

Answer (score 0):

Call [execSql](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL)

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
  switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)){
    case URI_1:
     SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     db.execSql("insert into table1 (field1, field2,...) 
     select field1, field2... from table2 where ...");
     return uri;
}
```

Comment: this you example have to return uri "public Uri insert..." of newly inserted row for the ContentProvider to watch db changes..

Comment: You can return the same URI passed to insert. Updated my answer.

Comment: There is no problem if you return the same URI.